# google document list api thumbnail link url

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I have a couple of questions about the url returned for the thumbnail link in document list api:
1) is the url public? (does not seem to be access controlled)
2) does the url remain the same no matter when we get the link (is the url time limited or anything like that)?

Regards,
LT

Comment: From what I can tell the URL changes each time you request a file listing (using files.list) and it is a public URL with no access control. I haven't tested the expiry time yet, but I expect it would.